#  get selected item id in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I get the select item in a listbox and pass it on to another class. At the moment it does display the item id.

```
 private void moveup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());

            }
        }
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, use SelectedItems[i].Text instead of SelectedItems[i].ToString()

```
private void moveup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].Text);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the text from the listbox?
Instead of .ToString(), use .text

```
 private void moveup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].text);

            }
        }
```

To pass it to another class, you can then use it as a parameter or save it as an independent variable, or save the selected items to a list, then pass that to a class.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your object to the listbox collection it accepts a object then cast selected Item to whatever type you are using.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly do you mean by passing it a to a new class?

if you are creating a new class, you can use it in the constructor, by defining a constructor which accepts a string parameter

if you are setting property of a class, you can pass it as a parameter to a public method of the class or you can set it directly too.

Answer (score 0):

let the list box is lstOptions.

So lstOptions.SelectedItems[0].text

Gives you first selected item's TEXT in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your selected item to the destination type and pass it to another object.

```
otherObject.PassObject(listBox1.SelectedItems as WhatEver);
```